# getTokenForcingRefresh deprecated in Firebase. What to replace it?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

In a recent version of `Firebase`, `getTokenForcingRefresh` was deprecated. I'm using it because auth tokens expire and I need to be able to refresh the token and retry a rest command when it fails. What is the right replacement for this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `getIDTokenForcingRefresh:completion` API instead of deprecated one.

Please take a look at `FIRUser` class documentation here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRUser.h#L307